# Link is appending instead of opening new link

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink

I have an issue where I'm trying to open a link, but instead of opening the link, it's incorrectly appending the link. I've tried so many things, but no luck.

**Error:**

```
Cannot GET /users/123453/www.apple.com
```

**Button.tsx (Tried #1):**

```js
    <Button
      block
      onClick={() => window.location.replace("www.apple.com")}
    >
      Title
    </Button>
```

**Button.tsx (Tried #2):**

```js
    <Button
      block
      onClick={() => window.location.href = "www.apple.com"}
    >
      Title
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try, window.location = "https://www.apple.com", will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **absolute URLs** when giving stand-alone links.

> An absolute URL is a ‘full’ URL or one that contains the entire
> address of the page.

In your case, add https, that is, replace *[www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com)* with *https://www.apple.com*

```
 <Button
      block
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href='https://www.apple.com';
      }}
    >
      Title
    </Button>
```